# Futuristic movie with a totalitarian government consisting of seniors, where the protagonist learns of colors from an apple

Tags: story-identification, movie

This movie where takes place in a futuristic world; I think they call it a perfect community: everything is white and the people abide by the laws set up by an organization consisting of seniors.

They monitor everyone in this community to ensure that everyone is obeying the rules; the first half of the movie was black and white until the protagonist learned about colors from an apple.

I remember these scenes in the movie:

- The young people were having a graduation ceremony
- There's a man in a huge library that is willing to help the protagonist about memories or something like that
- Something is being done with babies, forgot exactly what.
- The protagonist wants to gain independence from the seniors that govern the community, seems that these seniors have been hiding something from the community people.

Comment: The apple is the one thing in color in a scene in the film [*Pleasantville*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleasantville_(film)), and increasing color in the world follows.

Comment: @Lexible Yep--it's practically _Pleasantville_-- Just transfer it to 100 or so years in the future.

Answer (score 29):

Is it possible that you're thinking of [the 2014 adaptation of *The Giver*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Giver_(film))?

> Following a calamity referred to as The Ruin, society is reorganized into a series of communities, and all memories of the past are held by one person, the Receiver of Memory. Since the Receiver of Memory is the only individual in the community who has the memories from before, he must advise the Chief Elder, and the other Elders, on the decisions for the community.
>
> Jonas (Brenton Thwaites) is a 16-year-old boy who is anxious about the career he will be assigned (along with everyone else). His two best friends are Asher (Cameron Monaghan) and Fiona (Odeya Rush).
>
> On the day of graduation, everyone is assigned a career. Jonas is briefly skipped, as he has not been assigned a career. Instead, Jonas is to become the next Receiver of Memory, and progressively receive memories from the past receiver, The Giver (Jeff Bridges). Upon assuming his role as The Receiver, Jonas learns of the Giver's past and of his child, Rosemary (Taylor Swift), who preceded Jonas as Receiver of Memory. She was so distraught from the memories that she committed suicide, by what the Community calls "releasing". They regard its nature as mysterious; the audience learns that it is death by lethal injection. Jonas begins to teach his findings to his friend Fiona, with whom he decides to share the idea of emotions. Fiona, who is unable to fully comprehend the idea of emotion, is unsure how she feels. Jonas then kisses Fiona, an action which is antiquated and unknown to the community, which Jonas gained through memory....

As you can see, the film does transition from black-and-white to color (54 seconds in):

In Chapter 3 of the book, it's revealed in a flashback that the first hint that Jonas can potentially see color involves an apple which briefly *changes* before shifting back to seeming normal. I'm not certain if the same scene shows up in the film, but the second official trailer does show him realizing colors from an apple.

Comment: I am pretty sure his transformation comes from the "Giver" directly. I think the "apple" is given from the young man to the young woman. And this is the movie that came to mind when I read the question.

Comment: Yep, pretty sure this is the right answer

Comment: *"I have not found the scene with the apple.."* Perhaps you're referring to the book, but a red apple is shown several times in the trailer. Once is when he's using it between his hand and an injecting station to allow the apple to take whatever is being injected.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Specifically, the scene where "the protagonist learned about colors from an apple."

Comment: Oh right, NVM. :P